# Display of contact information when searching by tags using smart search

Tags: joomla-3.x, smartsearch

I want smart search to go directly to page when the query have ONE result.

I have a list of contacts, all assigned a number of area codes.

What I've done so far is:
- Enabled smart search
- added smart search module
- added area codes as tags in each contact
- Indexed content
- made a search filter only searching tags

I want the user to be able to search for the nearest contact by inserting their area code in the search box. When doing this I want the contact information to come right up on the page.

However, when searching the tag appears as a link, when clicking, then the contact name as a link, when clicking, then the contact information.

I want to skip the two first steps.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do that, or know of any extension to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SmartSearch component doesn't support showing a page directly. But I think it should be easy to do in a layout override for the results page. The overrides can be created in the template manager (see Help Page: [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aHow_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides))
You need to create the override for `com_finder`.

You could then check in this override if the results array `$this->results` contains only one element and redirect to the URL instead of showing the results page.

The second step could be changed using a custom smart search plugin. You can copy the existing one, rename it and adjust it so it indexes the desired URL. For more information about how to create a finder plugin, see this doc page: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in